# Designing a sorting algorithm from scratch

Tags: python, beginner, sorting

I'm taking a Python course and the current assignment is to create an algorithm that sorts numbers in ascending order (without using built-in sorting functions). I've had no programming experience before taking this course, so this might be a bit rough.

I got my script to successfully sort the numbers by figuring out the smallest number in the list each time through and moving it to a new list. This is obviously not very efficient since it has to loop dozens of times just for a short list, but I'm happy I finally got something to work! (Also, I think I need another `elif` to account for lists with repeat numbers.)

How can I clean it up? Is it more complex than it needs to be? I know there are far more efficient ways to sort, but I don't want to just copy someone else's established algorithm. I'd like to keep as much of this code in tact as possible while nipping and tucking.

```
def sortFunc(*arg):

    numList = list(arg)                     # Converts arguments into a list
    print('Before sorting: ',numList)       # Prints that list before sorting happens
    numSort = []                            # Creates an empty list to put sorted numbers into
    i = 0                                   # This is the index
    a = 1                                   # 'a' is the comparison number (this is the magic sauce)

    while numList:                          # As long as numList has numbers in it, loop the following

        if numList[i] == numList[-1] and\
           numList[i] <= a:                 # If we're at the final index AND that last number is smaller than 'a'
            basket = numList.pop(i)         # then place that number in a basket
            numSort.append(basket)          # and dump the basket into the new list (numSort)
            i = 0

        elif numList[i] == numList[-1]:     # Otherwise, if we reach the last position in numList 
            i = 0                           # reset the index back to the first position
            a = a+1                         # and make the comparison number a little bigger

        elif numList[i] <= a:               # If we're anywhere else in the list and that number is smaller than 'a'
            basket = numList.pop(i)         # then pop that number into the basket
            numSort.append(basket)          # and dump it unceremoniously into the new list (numSort)
            i = 0                           # Then reset the index back to the first position
            a = a+1                         # and make the comparison number a little bigger

        else:                               # If none of those things happen
            i = i+1                         # then move on to the next number in the list

    print('After sorting: ',numSort)        # Once the while loop is up, print the result!


sortFunc(67, 45, 2, 13, 1, 998)
```

Comment: http://bigocheatsheet.com/#sorting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Not bad for a first attempt!**

I have made some modifications, none of them are towards speed/effency.

1. Follow PEP8 style guide for naming your variables and functions. It just the way to write python.
2. Don't print in functions, print outside functions
3. Don't accept `*args` to just make it a list. Accept a variable you expect to be a list then just act on it as if it were a list.
4. Throw away variables are handy if you plan on using them more than once. But if it is just to append it to another list just nest the operation.

   ```
   basket = numList.pop(i)
   numSort.append(basket)
   ```

   becomes

   ```
   numSort.append(numList.pop(i))
   ```
5. Use `i += 1` instead of `i = i + 1`, it's just cleaner.
6. You're comments are a bit over verbose. I didn't update any comments so they may be wrong in the modified code below.

Here is the modified code.

```
def sort_func(values):
    num_sort = []  # Creates an empty list to put sorted numbers into
    i = 0  # This is the index
    a = 1  # 'a' is the comparison number (this is the magic sauce)

    while values:  # As long as numList has numbers in it, loop the following
        if values[i] == values[-1] and values[i] <= a:  # If we're at the final index AND that last number is smaller than 'a'
            num_sort.append(values.pop(i))
            i = 0
        elif values[i] == values[-1]:  # Otherwise, if we reach the last position in numList
            i = 0  # reset the index back to the first position
            a += 1  # and make the comparison number a little bigger
        elif values[i] <= a:  # If we're anywhere else in the list and that number is smaller than 'a'
            num_sort.append(values.pop(i))
            i = 0  # Then reset the index back to the first position
            a += 1  # and make the comparison number a little bigger
        else:  # If none of those things happen
            i += 1  # then move on to the next number in the list
    return num_sort

my_list = [67, 45, 2, 13,  13, 1, 998]
print("Before sorting {}".format(my_list))
my_list = sort_func(my_list)
print("After sorting {}".format(my_list))
```

Answer (score 1):

Congrats of making your own sorting algorithm!

### Speed/Efficiency

There are plenty of sorts on Wikipedia that are more efficient, if you want to take a look at them. I added rough speed (given random data) and difficulty estimates:

- [Bubble sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort) (very slow, very easy)
- [Selection sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_sort) (slow, easiest)
- [Insertion sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insertion_sort) (also slow, but harder)
- [Merge sort](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort) (fast, hard)
- [Quicksort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort) (faster, also hard)

### Output

Typically it is bad practice to put a print statement inside a function, because you don't want your console flooded with text if you are calling that function a bunch of times. Instead, you can do `return numSort` inside your function and `print(sortFunc(myList))` outside.

### Naming

Now, I'm sure you will also get answers pertaining to variable names, but I'm not a stickler for that, plus your variables and functions seem good already.

Happy coding!

Comment: You may want to add that Bubble sort is linear in the best case (ie very fast). While the others (except insertion) don't have this property.

Comment: @LokiAstari changed to include random data